# Azure App Service SSL certificate binding not automatically updated

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

We bought an SSL certificate through the Azure portal for an App Service and made it autorenew. A while ago the certificate had renewed as it should. This morning we noticed SSL didn't work anymore.  This was because the the wrong SSL certificate was bound to the App Service.

Do I really have to update the bindings manually every year?

[image]

Comment: I am also in the same position. Reading this article `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internals-of-app-service-certificate/` I understand that the renew and the sync should have happened automatically. But somehow it did not for us. Maybe clicking this Sync button could help ?? Not sure I could test this anymore, since I went through the manual process already. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to update binding manually in SSL binding if you will renew SSL certificate but if your SSL has already IP-based then you won’t have to set the IP binding again. You should also refer this https://riccardo-moschetti.org/2016/02/07/renewing-an-ssl-certificate-for-a-website-hosted-in-azure/ for step by step information with images

Comment: Kind of sad that nothing is mentioned about renewal in the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site